# Как составить запрос на удаление из трех таблиц

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть таблицы general_table, adress_tble, education_table. нужно удалить из таблиц данные по одной персоне, зная только ID персоны.
ЗАПРОС не работает. Помогите разобраться!

```
DELETE general_table.Personname, general_table.Personsoname, general_table.Personmiddlename, general_table.Datebir, general_table.Inn, general_table.Note, adress_tble.Country, adress_tble.City, adress_tble.Street, adress_tble.House, adress_tble.Apartment, adress_tble.Hkey, education_table.FirstEducation, education_table.Specialty, education_table.StartYear, education_table.EndYear, education_table.HightEducation, education_table.HightSpecialty, education_table.HightStartYear, education_table.HightEndYear, education_table.SecondHigherEducation, education_table.SecondHightSpecialty, education_table.SecondHightStartYear, education_table.SecondHightEndYear,  general_table.Adress, general_table.Education FROM general_table, education_table, adress_tble WHERE general_table.Inn = @text AND general_table.Adress = adress_tble.ID AND general_table.Education = education_table.ID
```

Comment: >нужно удалить из данные по одной персоне

эмм..что?

Comment: Вы там в запросе отдельные поля удаляете или что?

Comment: Извиняюсь за ошибку) Мне нужно удалить данные из всех таблиц, по определенной персоне.

Comment: так удаляйте записи, а не поля. Что-то вы тут смешали всё в кучу

Answer (score 2):

Без структуры, конечно, можно и ошибиться. Но если я правильно все понял, то есть введенный ИНН (содержится в text), для которого надо удалить все данные из таблиц, с которыми он связан по ID из general_table.
Тогда делаем так:

`delete from <ТАБЛИЦА> where <ТАБЛИЦА>.<ССЫЛКА_НА_general_table_id> in (select id from general_table where Inn=@text)` - для каждой таблицы, которая ссылается на данные из `general_table` (само собой, <ТАБЛИЦА> меняем на имя таблицы, <`ССЫЛКА_НА_general_table_id`> - на имя поля, которое содержит id из general_table).
А в конце - `delete from general_table where general_table.Inn = @text`

А лучше это сделать на уровне триггера на удаление из general_table или на внешних ключах.

Comment: Спасибо большое!! Заработало!